# E-flat minor vs D-sharp minor?

Tags: guitar, chords, scales, chord-progressions, key

I'm a beginner guitar player, and I was working a little bit on my theory as well as learning songs I like with the song *Feel Good Inc.*, by Gorillaz. So, I was looking at the chords and I was trying to guess the key, and I said D-sharp minor.

I looked up the key to see if I was right, and Google said E-flat minor.

Now, I know that they're technically the same thing, but I was wondering if there's any inherent use or meaningful difference in making in saying the song is in E-flat minor vs D-sharp minor.

Maybe for other instruments in the song that aren't guitar? I wouldn't know since that's all I play.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: While the duplicate questions is about the parallel minor keys, the question and answers all are about the general concept of enharmonic keys.

Comment: @Dom - yes, the question itself is asking something different from the other question, but the answers explain both queries.

Comment: @Tim But that would mean if someone posts an extremely long article with various musical concepts as an answer to some question (Q), we could mark something like 600 questions as duplicates of that one question, because that one answer covered the 600 other questions, even if the original question Q didn't ask about any stuff asked in any of the 600 other questions.